# Let $q : S^{2n+1} → CP^n$ be the usual quotient map. Is $q$ a covering space?

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $q : S^{2n+1} → CP^n$ be the usual quotient map. Is $q$ a covering space ?

I only know the definitions. But how to do this one? Any ideas please.

Comment: This is a common and general result about space modulo a group that acts nicely. You should rather look at a textbook

Comment: The fibers of $q$ are circles. The fibers of a covering map are discrete.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Can't we argue like this : as you mentioned  the fibers of a point is the under the action. Then taking a path connected open set around the point  in $C P^n$ will have the fiber an annulus kind of region with it's boundaries removed, which is not simply connected so we can't get a homeomorphism as required. Now can't we extend this idea for all open sets i.e. which also have more than one path components similarly ?

Answer (score 3):

It is not a covering, because both spaces do not have the same dimension. But you have a fibration $S^1\rightarrow S^{2n+1}\rightarrow CP^n$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space#Topology

Comment: I guess the sphere is real

Comment: @AlexL What other sphere were you thinking about?